# Does Alamofire support HTTP/2's new features?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to know if Alamofire supports HTTP/2's new features like:

- Multi requests and responses in same connection
- Push feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alamofire supports all of the same standards as `URLSession`, which includes HTTP/2.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/935

Let me know if this answers your question and if I should give more Context.

Comment: According to that , multiple requests will sending via one connection , is it right?

Comment: Can I stop that for some reasons?

Comment: And can I use push feature?

Comment: Alamofire is limited to the HTTP/2 support offered NSURLSession. NSURLSession offers no exposed support for either `PUSH_PROMISE` or the HTTP/2 stream